# convert the time using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Using [datefns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) how can i convert the below format to the expected one

```
const input = "3:0:0:0"

const output: "3am"
```

What i have tried.

```
import format from 'date-fns/format'

const input = "3:0:0:0"
const output = format(input, "HH:MM:SS:NS")

console.log(output) // getting invalid date.
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-forked-w4c7o

Comment: I do not see why you would need a library for that, but even a library needs a proper date object.

Comment: But i am having only the time, i didn't find to convert the time to the desired format with am and pm so should i write a custom function for this as the library doesn't support for the time

Comment: I don't even SEE `NS` here https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format - I assume you mean MS but that is not the output you want

Comment: so only way is to split, "3:0:0:0".split(":") and write a custom logic isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without this library I would use vanilla JS and

```js
const fmtTime = str => {
  let [hh,mm,ss,ms] = str.split(':')
  return `${hh}${+mm>0?`:${mm}`:''}${hh>12?'pm':'am'}`
};
const input1 = "3:30:0:0";
const input2 = "3:0:0:0";

console.log(fmtTime(input1))
console.log(fmtTime(input2))
```

Comment: This worked, but just one doubt, if i have case something like const input1 = "3:30:0:0"; 
const input2 = "3:30:0:0";  what will be the right way
console.log(`${hh}:${mm} ${hh>12?"pm":"am"}`)

Comment: yep so in this case const input = "3:0:0:0" the output will be 3:0 am, which should be actually outputted as 3am so for this checking i tried of adding +(mm) > 0 && mm, but this will print false in the output. So how to solve this